# Ionic2 and Aframe in iphone

Tags: ionic2, aframe, webvr, 360-virtual-reality

I'm making a VR 360 application using Ionic2 and Aframe. It should be easy because Aframe is all you need to do it (you set a video asset and load it from a videosphere primitive) but I don´t get the desire result. I have the problem with Ios (works fine in Android and in browser), when I run the application in my iphone the video is played in Iphone player and not in my application therefore I don´t have 360 efect.
I add *playsinline* like documentation says, I add

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

too, but not work. I use the next code:

```
<a-scene>

  <a-assets>
     <video id="video" src="assets/img/video1.mp4" loop crossorigin playsinline></video>
     <img id="cubes-thumb" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/thumb-cubes.jpg">
     <img id="cubes" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/cubes.jpg">

  </a-assets>

  <a-videosphere src="#video" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>
  <a-image class="link" src="#cubes" position="0 0 -1"></a-image>
   <!--<a-entity id="links" layout="type: line; margin: 1.5" position="0 -1 -4">
    <a-entity template="src: #cubes" data-src="#cubes" data-thumb="#cubes-thumb"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>-->

  <a-entity camera look-controls>
    <a-cursor id="cursor"
      animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 150"
      animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500"
      event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; color: green"
      event-set__2="_event: mouseleave; color: black"
      raycaster="objects: .link"
      material="color:black">
    </a-cursor>
  </a-entity>


</a-scene>
```

I thought the problem could be autoplay and I have disable it and I trigger *play* with a button but I have the same result.

Anyidea what more can I try?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredible, all weekend searching for an answer and after I post my question I've found it

I needed to add  to my config.xml

Here is the answer that helped me

[Playing video inline in Ionic/Phonegap (webkit-playsinline not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982396/playing-video-inline-in-ionic-phonegap-webkit-playsinline-not-working)